# Flink sql kafka sink with complex data type

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I need some help with getting flink kafka connect to produce correct data when data is of complex object type

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SOURCE_TABLE
(
    source      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id          VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    contentJson VARCHAR NOT NULL
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic-pattern' = '${source_topic_pattern}',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${source_kafka_servers}',
    'properties.group.id' = '${kafka_consumer_group_id}'
);
```

contentJson example

```
"contentJson": "{\"field1\":[{\"identityId\":\"21ade8be05f548a983acf68a8ab5ff73\",\"IdsAfter\":[\"seg-id-1\"]}]}"
```

if i have this sink defined as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SINK_TABLE
(
    field1      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic-pattern' = 'SINK_TABLE',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${source_kafka_servers}',
    'properties.group.id' = '${kafka_consumer_group_id}'
);
```

here the field1 is a string, json is enclosed with in quotes

```
"[{\"identityId\":\"21ade8be05f548a983acf68a8ab5ff73\"}]"
```

i can define the  field as Array of ROW I get what I need but I need to write a UDF that converts the json into RowData using GenericRowData.of() method
if my sink is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SINK_TABLE
(
    field1      ARRAY<ROW<identityId STRING>>
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic-pattern' = 'SINK_TABLE',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${source_kafka_servers}',
    'properties.group.id' = '${kafka_consumer_group_id}'
);
```

output has data like this

```
[{"identityId":"21ade8be05f548a983acf68a8ab5ff73"}]
```

How do i do this without using udf to convert this to row data. Better do I get the required output without defining that as a complex object in the sink
i have tried `field1 RAW` i get an error.

Comment: I believe that you should be able to use something like `contentJson ROW(`identityId ` VARCHAR)` in your DDL

Comment: This is just a simple example. ContentJson can be really complex with hundreds of fields. Is there a way not to define a complex data type on the sink but still emit a json ?

Comment: You can consider mapping the entire JSON input as a VARCHAR and use a JSON function that extract the identityId via a JSONPath.

Comment: How to define my ddl for sink table if I need json  ? I can’t use varchar there as it’s produce a string.

Comment: You specify `json` as the format for your sink, then it will produce JSON out of the box. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/formats/json/

Comment: It should produce json, for complext type, it produce a JSONized string, i.e the json is inside a `'"` Like `"[{\"identityId\":\"21ade8be05f548a983acf68a8ab5ff73\"}]"` . This is not desirable. Only way around i to define the ddl with field type as ROW. Question is there a way to avoid specific ROW type and still get json data like  `[{"identityId":"21ade8be05f548a983acf68a8ab5ff73"}]` ?
i need to send data like Map<String, Object>, for this i cant use ROW, as i dont know all element in side a ROW